# Mail Queue processed but the Laravel don't send email

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The Mail::queue method processes the service but does not send the mail.Nothing arrives in the destination email. The redis is working normally.[image]

```
 $data = ['nome_prefeitura'=>$gestora->pessoa->nome,'empresa'=>$n->economico->pessoa->nome,'pessoa'=>$n->pessoa->nome,'link'=>$link,'nome_secretaria'=>'Secretaria Fazenda de Dom Joaquim.'];
         Mail::queue('layout_email.email_nfse', $data, function ($m) use ($n) {
             $m->from('nfe@mail.com.br', 'NFS-e');
             $m->to($n->email_envio, $n->pessoa->nome)->subject('Notificação de emissão de NFS-e');
         });



 CACHE_DRIVER=redis
    SESSION_DRIVER=redis
    QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.com.br
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=nfenfe@mail.com.br
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my email server and it worked.

Comment: Hi, mine is working when i use send, if i use queue, yes it is showing job in  jobs table and in the terminal it shows that it has been processed but nothing arrived to my email.